# 'DevExpress' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, devexpress, maui

I am working on a .Net MAUI app with standard template. I am using DataForm from DevExpress on android at this point.
It was working completely fine but suddenly solution started to fail with Error
'DevExpress' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?).

Issue is in the autogenerated view file.

Could you help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove and reinstall the DevEx nugets

Comment: Still doesnt work, it gives the same error. Is it a known issue?

Comment: Submit an issue with DevExpress support.

Comment: Thank you guys, created an issue with them too. Havent heard anything as of now. Will see if they give me any resolution will post it here.

Comment: Can you post the answer when they get back to you? I am getting the same issue. What's worse is that I am unable to uninstall the NuGet package because it says he cannot even find it! Eek!

Comment: @FifthCloud same happened to me, when I tried uninstalling it couldnt find it and uninstall it, i kept retrying and it finally did uninstall. 
I have actually ditched DevExpress and used Syncfusion community license instead but will let you know what they say

Comment: @user5678, So I finally figured out what the issue was for my particular situation. In order to get DevExpress working for my Maui Project I had to specify the .Net Framework to target *only* iOS and Android and everything worked! Double-check your solution is targeting those OS only and you *should* be fine. Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: @FifthCloud it worked. my project was also targeting mac and windows. Can you please answer this and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get DevExpress to work with Maui you have to make sure the .Net Framework targets *only* Android and/or iOS.

Select your solution and double-check what OS you are targeting.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios;net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
```